# What does SleepAndRun() and ThreadFunc() do in this code?

Tags: multithreading, c++11, timer

I want to implement a timer.h for my code. So i surf the net and found this piece of code working fine. but i would like to know about What **SleepAndRun()** and **ThreadFunc()** do in this code and why he define like that??
thread for Asynchronse code execution.i only understand that in std::this_thread::sleep_for(interval) is this_thread- current theard which created the timer object
        sleep_for() will block thread for interval ,but why is it use here?

```
    class Timer { std::thread Thread;

    bool Alive = false;
    long CallNumber = -1L;//no. of times function going to call
    long repeat_count = -1L;//no. of times function already called

    std::chrono::milliseconds interval = std::chrono::milliseconds(0);

    std::function<void(void)> funct = nullptr;

        void SleepAndRun ()
            {
            std::this_thread::sleep_for(interval);
            if (Alive)
                Function ()();
            } 

        void ThreadFunc ()
            {
            if (CallNumber == Infinite)
                while (Alive)
                    SleepAndRun ();
            else
                while (repeat_count--)
                    SleepAndRun ();
            }

        public: static const long Infinite = -1L;
 Timer () {} 

    Timer(const std::function<void(void)> &f) : funct (f) {}

    Timer(const std::function<void(void)> &f,
          const unsigned long &i,
          const long repeat = Timer::Infinite) : funct (f),
                                                 interval (std::chrono::milliseconds(i)), CallNumber (repeat) {}



    void Start (bool Async = true)
        {

        if (IsAlive ())//FOUNDING NOT ALIVE .THN alive =true
            return;

        Alive = true;

        repeat_count = CallNumber;

        if (Async)
            Thread = std::thread(ThreadFunc, this);
        else 
            this->ThreadFunc ();
        }

    void Stop ()
        {

        Alive = false;


        Thread.join ();
        }
    void SetFunction (const std::function<void (void)> &f)
        {
        funct = f;
        }
    bool IsAlive () const {return Alive;}
    void RepeatCount (const long r)
        {

        if (Alive)
            return;
        CallNumber = r;
        }

    long GetLeftCount () const {return repeat_count;}

    long RepeatCount () const {return CallNumber;}
    void SetInterval (const unsigned long &i)
        {

        if (Alive)
            return;;

        interval = std::chrono::milliseconds(i);
        }

    unsigned long Interval () const {return interval.count();}

    const std::function<void(void)> &Function () const
        {

        return funct;
        }
    };
```

Comment: Doing homework does not mean you should copy things you don't understand from the net and then ask the community for help. Please do a serious attempt to understand the problem yourself. Also, this is not a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) as there is some context missing. E.g. what is `Function`?. Also, the `{` on the first line is never closed. So, that will never compile.

Comment: @AdrianW iam not doing homework. Iam just asking for help so that i can understand how its like that.

Comment: So I am sorry. But anyway you should copy things you don't understand. And thanks for the edit. This looks much more complete now.

Comment: @AdrianW at last can you please clear my doubt on this by explaining what i asked.

Answer (score 0):

When `Start()` is called, the method `ThreadFunc()` will be run. This will take place immediately (i.e. in the current thread) if the parameter `Async` is `false`. If `Async` is `true` (which is the default when you call `Start()` without parameters), a new thread is created and `ThreadFunc()` will be run in that thread.

`ThreadFunc()` now calls `SleepAndRun ()` which waits for a time which must be set *previously*  by a call to `SetInterval()`. The it calls a function which you also must set *previously* by a call to `SetFunction()`. The parameter to `SetFunction()` is of type `std::function<void()>` which means this can be any function taking no parameters and returning no result.

Why is this done this way? To allow the flexibility of

- running in the same or in a different thread
- calling a function you supply at runtime